# Probability over time period

Tags: probability

Can someone help me with this probability question. Lets say I know the following:

Probability of event from time period 1 to period 2 (x)
Probability of event from time period 1 to period 3 (y)
What would be the probability of time period 2 to period 3?

Thanks in advance? John

Answer (score 0):

Let $E$ be the event.

$$\mathbb{P}[E\in[1,3]]=\mathbb{P}[E\in[1,2]]+\mathbb{P}[E\in[2,3]]$$

$$\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}[E\in[2,3]]=y-x.$$

Comment: Thank You, Just so I am clear, if the the p(E) from t1 to t5 is 5%, and the p(E) from t1 to t10 is 12%.  Then the p(E) from t5 to t10 is simply 7%?

Comment: Yes... think about it a little more it should make sense.